# Javascript equivalent to explode

Tags: javascript

My initial idea is to grab just a certain number from a URL receiving using JSON

**http://fh13.fhcdn.com/static/img/nations/14.png**

How would i receive just the **14** using Javascript ? would i use split() or is that not the same ?

Comment: Sure, `split()` is like `explode()`, if that's your question. Why don't you at least make an attempt at writing some code to accomplish this fairly simple goal yourself?

Comment: @MattBall thank you very much, I just needed confirmation !

Comment: `url.split('/').pop().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');` If you want it off the last part (filename).

Comment: `var num=parseInt(URL.substring(URL.lastIndexOf("/")+1))` if you always have a number and no leading 0s

Comment: @JaredFarrish liking the pop()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you always have the same structure can be used

```
var url = "http://fh13.fhcdn.com/static/img/nations/14.png";
var n = ((url.split(".")[2]).split("/"))[4]; //return 14
```

Comment: I tried your code, returns undefined? And what if there's a dot (or many of 'em) in the file name?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RpKEu/

Comment: this is pretty rigid...

Comment: "if you always have the same structure can be used"

Comment: @CurtisCrewe: are you looking for something that works, or is robust?

Comment: @CurtisCrewe: By all means, don't choose my answer, but IMHO this doesn't deserve the tick when there are at least 3 other *much* better answers.

Comment: All responses are validity, I could say yours, but it is "solved" the problem and sometimes simplicity is the solution

Comment: I'm all for tackling things in more way than one. But I only comment because the other solutions offered are *simpler, neater*, and much more *robust* than your answer. IMO, they are hands down, better answers in every single aspect.

Answer (score 1):

To grab all numbers:

```
var url = "http://fh13.fhcdn.com/static/img/nations/14.png";
url.match(/\d+/g);   // returns ["13","14"], so url.match(/\d+/g).pop() == "14"
```

Or Grab "14.png" and then parseInt():

```
parseInt( url.match( /\d+\D*$/g ) );
```

Comment: Would that not also get the 13?

Comment: @Jace: explained in the comment

Comment: url.match(/\/(\d+)\.png$/)[1]

Comment: You could replace the png with \w+ and avoid the need for parseInt()

Comment: @user1936123: the reason why you use `.pop()` is that you don't know how many numbers will be in the URL - pop() will return the last one, regardless if there was one match, or multiple.  Additionally, what if you have a url thats like `www.google.com/14.png?someotherurlmagic=15.gif`, when "14" is really the wanted string - it's best to let the author decide.  Finally, it's better to use `[^\d]*` (or `\D*`) than `\w*`

Comment: Your second regex in your answer would match the 15.gif at the end of the query string provided in your comment, as the 15 would not match the `[^\d]`, but would match the `\d+` before it.  It chooses the one at the end, because of the `$`.

Comment: In regard to `.pop()`, you only return one match with the `$`, so you know it will always be `[1]`.

Comment: To avoid issues with the query string and potential numbers in the extension, you could go with `url.match(/\/(\d+)\.[^\/\.\?]+(\?.*)?$/)[1]`.

Comment: @user1936123: regarding your `$` - correct it's an example and not an all-encompassing solution, which we can only provide some solutions, since there is no known structure and we don't know what can happen or what the OP really wants.

Comment: @user1936123: **Quote:** `In regard to .pop(), you only return one match with the $, so you know it will always be [1]` **Response:** The pop() example returns an array of all numbers, `pop()` will return the last one, which again, may or may not be wanted (it's only an example of how to use pop) --- in regards to your regex, if you're going that route, you may consider splitting or truncating the string, but I think that would work -- again, we still don't know what the OP really is working with, what may come up, and what is really wanted

Comment: [jsfiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/ReMB7/)

Comment: @user1936123: just briefly looked at the fiddle, I already like what I see -- if I have more time I'll give a greater look at it later and delete this comment then, but note: we don't know if it should be "14" or "15", all we can do is provide some tools, and hope the OP knows how to use them

Comment: Agreed. Note that I do much prefer the regex method over the split/explode one.

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
var l = "http://fh13.fhcdn.com/static/img/nations/14.png";
var larr = l.split("/");
var laast = larr.pop();
console.log(laast.split(".")[0]); //gets 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes split is the way to go...

```
var n = '14.jpg';
var p = n.split('.');
console.log(p[0]);
```

Also if you have a dot in the file name, you can try this:

```
var n = 'file.14.jpg';
var p = n.split('.');
p.pop(); //removes the extension
console.log(p.join('.'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://fh13.fhcdn.com/static/img/nations/14.png";

var index = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var dotIndex = url.indexOf(".", index);

console.log(url.substring(index+1,dotIndex));  // Prints 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`. The first argument to it can be either a string or a regular expression. So if you wanted to split a string based on multiple deliminators, you could just form a quick regular expression of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

String's `.split` is more equivalent to `preg_split` (or the deprecated `split`) than it is to `explode`, since it takes a regular expression as well and its method of use is different, but it can be used in practically the same way.

```
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).split('.')[0]
```

You could also use the `.lastIndexOf('.')` as the second argument to `substring`.

Comment: Or just parseInt if no leading 0s